# Despite open port, Linux refuses to accept incoming connection

Tags: centos, firewall

I'm trying to set up a simple server to be accessible from the Internet. To do so, I have opened port 8080 by executing the following command:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
```

When I try to connect to my server by executing:

```
$ telnet my-external-ip 8080
```

I get:

```
telnet: connect to address my-external-ip: Connection refused
```

I have no problem when I connect to my server using local address, i.e. I can connect to http://localhost:8080/

I'm behind router but I set correct forwarding. I use CentOS Linux 7.

When I run

```
$ ss -tnlp |grep 8080
```

I get

```
LISTEN     0      128  :::8080 :::* users:(("java",pid=6836,fd=309))
```

**UPDATE**
As user *Paul H.* suggested in the comments, the reason behind why I couldn't connect is that my router doesn't allow for NAT loopback. My configuration of Linux was OK.

Comment: Is the listening socket bound to 127.0.0.1:8080 or to 0.0.0.0:8080? If the former, it can not accept connections from outside.

Comment: I can connect to either to 127.0.0.1:8080 or to 0.0.0.0:8080 if this is what you meant.

Comment: No, please run "netstat -ln | grep 8080" to see the address on which your process listens.

Comment: I get `tcp6 0 0 :::8080  :::*  LISTEN`.

Comment: do you get the "connection refused" immediately? if blocked by firewall, this would more probably lead to a timeout error I think... So I would look more closely to logs and configuration around telent server.

Comment: I get it immediately.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the firewall service?

Comment: Are you trying to access your external ip from inside your internal network or from an offsite machine?

Comment: Yes, I restarted by executing `sudo systemctl restart firewalld`. I'm trying access from my own computer (the same as the servers is running on).

Comment: Your router may not support NAT loopback.

Comment: So, Without NAT loopback is it not possible to connect to my own machine using external IP?

Comment: Not from behind router.

Comment: This [link](https://superuser.com/q/1047745) might help.

Comment: You were right. I can access my server outside my local network.

Comment: `lsop -i TCP:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Your server seems to be listening on IPv6 address "tcp6 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN", not IPv4. So make sure you are connecting to proper address.